# POST request with a json body javascript

Tags: javascript, json, request

I need to make a POST request with a json object in the body. The request is the following:

```
request({
        encoding: 'utf8',
        url: 'myUrl',
        json: true,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Auth-Token': ticket
        },
        json : JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"))
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")")))
            res.status(200).send('added')
            }
        )
```

The request doesn't do what it's supposed to do. However, if I use the JSON.stringify evaluation that i get with console.log to make a POST request to the same url with Postman, it works. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the `request` function? Where does it come from?

Comment: Why are you using the horrible `eval()` hack to parse JSON when you have the `JSON` object available?

Comment: Why are you parsing JSON only to **immediately** reencode the result as JSON?

Comment: *The request doesn't do what it's supposed to do.* — What **does** it do then? How is that different from what it is supposed to do?

Comment: The request does nothing. Doesn't post the json. The request function is from node.js request module. I parse JSON that way because the string i want to use as JSON is this one:  `var str = "{ policyTag : '" + policyName+ "', networkDevices : [{ deviceId : '" + deviceId + "'}]}"` so i need to respect the syntax. Evaluating it results in `{"policyTag":"policyName","networkDevices":[{"deviceId":"699a2e94-3e37-43ef-a751-6845501c4061"}]}` which works in postman.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ policyTag: policeName, networkDevices: [{deviceID: deviceId}]})` would almost certainly make more sense.

Comment: Does it really do "nothing"? Does the callback function not fire at all? Does no error get reported on the console?

Comment: I get status 200 if i print it with console.log in browser and no error on the console. I tried with that JSON and didn't work either.

Comment: If I GET all policies at that url it doesn't get posted, that's how i know it does nothing, while posting with postman, it works just fine.

Comment: I solved it by making a JSON object like this: `var obiect = {
        "policyTag" : policyName,
        "networkDevices" : [{
            "deviceId" : deviceId
        }]
    }' and passing it to the json in request.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just

```
json: JSON.stringify(str)
```

Forget the eval() function, it's not needed. str should be a javascript value, which will be converted to a JSON string.

Comment: Because that would double encode the result. `json: str` would make more sense.

Comment: The JSON should have this synthax: `{ "policyTag" : "x", "networkDevices" : [{ "deviceId" : "y" }] }`

Comment: I tried with json: str, json: JSON.stringify(str) and the eval one, but none work.

Comment: Well without knowing what str is, it's hard to tell. Incomplete question if you ask me.

Comment: Well I just need to get the synthax mentioned above in the request json. I find myself complicated by the array of objects, value of "networkDevices".